# Convergence of harmonic sum with a twist

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, summation

> Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ be the harmonic sum, but every third element is  multiplied by $(-2)$. Meaning $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1+\frac{1}{2}-2*\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-2*\frac{1}{6}\dots$. Determine if the sum converges.

So my attempt was to add parentheses so that we get:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1+\frac{1}{2}-2*\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-2*\frac{1}{6}\dots\rightarrow(1+\frac{1}{2}-2*\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-2*\frac{1}{6})\dots$$

Now adding the parentheses produces a new sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{3k-2}+\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{2}{3k})$. But this sum converges so this tells me nothing.
I don't know how to take it from here.

Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you that the series converges.  Let $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$  You have shown that $s_{3n}\to s$, say.

Given $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N$ such that $n>N\implies |s_{3n}-s|<\varepsilon$.  But also $\exists M$ such that $n>M \implies |s_{3n+1}-s_{3n}|<\varepsilon$ and $|s_{3n+2}-s_{3n}|<\varepsilon$  so that for $n>\max(N,M)$, $|s_n-s|<2\varepsilon$.

Comment: But in general, one can add parentheses to a divergent series and in place get a converging series. Why does it work here? Moreover, why is my sum $S_{3n}$?

Comment: Your sequence is $s_{3n}$ because you're adding in three terms at a time. $(a_1+a_2+a_3)= s_3;\ (a_1+a_2+a_3)+ (a_4+a_5+a_6) = s_6$ etc.  It works here because $s_{3n+1}$ and $s_{3n+2}$ get arbitrarily close to $s_{3n}$ as $n\to\infty$